# When cover the installation,Console print INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED.Please help me

Tags: android

I have my app at version 3.7.There is no property "android:sharedUserId" in AndroidManifest.xml.

But now,I'm going to update my app to 3.8. And add "android:sharedUserId" to AndroidManifest.xml for plugin function.

After finish that, I cover the installation, from 3.7 to 3.8, can't do that.

In the console window ,print out "INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED".

Besides that, remove "android:sharedUserId", it runs well.

Anybody has idea with this?

Answer (score 0):

> And add "android:sharedUserId" to AndroidManifest.xml for plugin function.

That will not work. You can never change the `android:sharedUserId` value from whatever it had been (including setting a value where you had not set it before).

Please use some other mechanism, like signature-level permissions, to secure the communications with your plugins.

Comment: In the way you said,do you have some exsample?

Comment: @user1484844: Most plugin samples are a little complicated. Here is a `ContentProvider` proxy that uses signature-level permissions: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/CPProxy Here is a `RemoteViews` publisher that uses a signature-level permission: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RemoteViews These are covered in detail in my book (http://commonsware.com/Android).